# Are no stub classes needed to host a standalone webservice ? don't we need a server to host a webservice?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, stub

1) I had been working on web services and was following

http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-hello-world-example-document-style/

http://theopentutorials.com/examples/java-ee/jax-ws/create-and-consume-web-service-using-jax-ws/

so here they use wsgen to create stub for the services .

But I tried and I am able to do it without stubs ......
I have the code here https://github.com/HarishAtGitHub/doc/tree/master/soapws%20without%20stub

so is stubs not needed any more ?
or is the stub creation done internally ?

2) I was in the assumption that the webservice hosting needs a server . But using the code I have in the github link provided above I am able to host it  standalone . what does standalone mean ?

don't we need a server ?

Answer (score 0):

I found answer by debugging and going inside jdk

1) Stub creation is done internally

2)Yes it needs a server . It does this using HttpServer internally .

what is the proof that the web service is internally run in a http server  ?

in EnpointImpl there is a code snippet

```
 // See if HttpServer implementation is available
    try {
        Class.forName("com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Couldn't load light weight http server", e);
    }
```

so if there is no HttpServer they will quit publishing

so this proves that somewhere inside they are using HttpServer

inside in EnpointImpl.createEndpoint they are getting some container

```
container = getContainer();
```

which turns out to be com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.ServerContainer

they are checking if it has a wsdl provided in 
EnpointImpl.java

```
/**
 * Gets wsdl from @WebService or @WebServiceProvider
 */
private @Nullable SDDocumentSource getPrimaryWsdl() {
    // Takes care of @WebService, @WebServiceProvider's wsdlLocation
    EndpointFactory.verifyImplementorClass(implClass);
    String wsdlLocation = EndpointFactory.getWsdlLocation(implClass);
    if (wsdlLocation != null) {
        ClassLoader cl = implClass.getClassLoader();
        URL url = cl.getResource(wsdlLocation);
        if (url != null) {
            return SDDocumentSource.create(url);
        }
        throw new ServerRtException("cannot.load.wsdl", wsdlLocation);
    }
    return null;
}
```

in our case we don’t have wsdl , we have only service class

**where are they creating http server ?**
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.ServerMgr
this class /**
 * Manages all the WebService HTTP servers created by JAXWS runtime.
 *
 * @author Jitendra Kotamraju
 */

```
from EnpointImpl.publish()
((HttpEndpoint) actualEndpoint).publish(address);
```

as endpoint is typcasted into HttpEndpoint, now

it goes to HttpEndpoint.publish() 
inside this HttpEndpoint.publish()

```
httpContext = ServerMgr.getInstance().createContext(address);
```

(https://upsource.jetbrains.com/lib/view/jdk7u10/com/sun/xml/internal/ws/transport/http/server/ServerMgr.java;nav:1535:1548:focused)
inside this createContext of com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.ServerMgr
class they are creating the HttpServer

```
server = HttpServer.create(inetAddress, 0);                             server.setExecutor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
String path = url.toURI().getPath();
logger.fine("Creating HTTP Context at = "+path);
HttpContext context = server.createContext(path);
server.start();
logger.fine("HTTP server started = "+inetAddress);
state = new ServerState(server);
servers.put(inetAddress, state);
return context;
```

so this is the HttpServer on which service runs ….